# OS X - DEAAD300 File Can't be seen via Terminal or Deleted

Tags: macos, terminal, gui, rm

OS X - 10.7.5

I have a file DEAAD300 on a users desktop that I can not delete.

EDIT - The file can not be opened either.

The icon that shows up looks like an Excel file (The user has Office 2011 installed).

When I try to delete the file via the GUI I get:

```
The item “DEAAD300” can’t be moved to the Trash because it can’t be deleted.
```

When I try to go and delete it via terminal, the file does not show with:

```
ls or ls -lah
```

At a loss where this file came from or what to do.  He said it showed up with out him doing anything...that I am not sure about.

Any help is great!

Comment: Is it still there after you restart? Is it a mounted drive or .dmg (disk utility will tell you)

Comment: Well, the user did a restart and it went away.  Very strange. Thanks @Ali!

Answer (score 0):

I often get that error as well. The files are shown on the desktop but not when opening a window for ~/Desktop/ in Finder. They have always disappeared after I have relaunched Finder or logged out and back in.

Comment: The user did not try either of these solutions.  I can not confirm or deny that this worked.  Thanks for the answer tho!